# Winter Bash 2020 - is it around the corner?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

Are we going to have Winter Bash 2020 soon?

Frankly speaking, I am quite tired of this year and want this holiday season. Probably, many people here share my feelings :)

Comment: this year we should all get automatically a *covid-mask* hat

Comment: @TemaniAfif you're not supposed to wear it as a hat but cover your mouth and nose.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah but I am expecting SO to give us a sophisticated mask that can be used as a hat as well ;) I will be disappointed if they will give us the one-use classic mask that we can get for less than 0.5$ (I already have a lot of them ...)

Comment: @TemaniAfif you know what's an effective way to protect yourself? You cannot catch the virus [if you're a carrot](http://villagepartyshop.co.uk/12341-thickbox_default/oversized-carrot-full-head-mask.jpg)

Comment: Hopefully not...

Comment: I would love to see this. But imagine a bee wearing a mask....

Comment: @VLAZ [Depends on the virus.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrot_virus_Y)

Comment: We need an antipodean hat for those of use for whom this is actually a summer bash

Comment: @TemaniAfif They listened. Congrats

Comment: @Machavity yeah! let's hope they will do the same for my other requests ;)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It has just started on December 16th at midnight UTC, just as predicted by the official countdown. Visit https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com for more information.

Comment: Surprised it's starting so late, last year's started this day last year according to their [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/09/tis-the-season-for-hats-join-us-for-winter-bash-2019/).

Comment: Will you update image in your post every day?

Comment: @Larnu last year it started on the 9th, this year it starts on the 16th. So, it appears it's [between 6 and 8 days later](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/).

Comment: Why you *ever* choose to say "between 6 and 8 days" instead of saying 7, when 7 is correct... >_< Yes it's "correct" that doesn't mean it's *"right"*.

Comment: @Larnu it's a recurring meme to refer to "6 to 8 <time units>". It's just around the time to be jolly, so I thought it appropriate to make a callback to it but use semantic humour as the punchline where "between 6 and 8" means "7". This serves as a double purpose - first it is a typical "engineering" (or sometimes called "mathematician") sort of joke where something *technically* correct but not very useful is said. Second, it's an inversion of the typical "6 to 8" scenario which usually means "unknown" and very 6 to 8 of anything. This time it's very literally and *exactly* between 6 and 8.

Comment: This years Winter Bash countdown doesn't look particularly "wintery" (or "Christmassy")?

Comment: So.. if the trend continues, next year, it may not start until december 23rd. If the duration is the same, we'll have winter bash in summer soon enough. I guess the Australians will be happy too then :)

Comment: @Scratte Well, winter only starts on the 21st so it's still got a while before it escapes the northern hemisphere winter

Comment: We Australians are implacably curmudgeonly, but thanks for thinking of us.

Comment: @Scratte That's my birthday! it may reset before it reaches the end of december though.

Comment: I'm not sure what will happen to my snippet when we hit zero- It'll depend on whether the counter stays on the page or not!

Comment: @zcoop98 We'll know it pretty soon

Comment: @zcoop98 Seems to be displaying the official winterbash page now :D

Answer (score 9):

Yes, as revealed in [The Loop: Our Community Roadmap for Q4 2020](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/10/21/the-loop-our-community-roadmap-for-q4-2020/) blog post:

> Winter Bash and Stack Gives Back
> It’s Q4, and that means it’s time for our favorite Winter events. This year you’ll see some fun new hats as we work to refresh the contest and introduce some new challenges for Winter Bash.

And see the official [countdown page](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/).

It will start December 16th at midnight UTC.

#### Now It's started! [Go here!](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's just sad that "the loop" was intended to gather feedback of sorts and community barely knows about results. On a plus side, Hats!!!

Comment: It just started!

Comment: Hooray! Yay yay yay!