# Can we have masks for Winter Bash 2020 instead of hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

Since [Winter Bash 2020 is just around the corner](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403498/winter-bash-2020-is-it-around-the-corner), I thought it would be fun to have masks this year instead of hats.

Masks would seem very 2020.

Comment: What is a mask but a poorly positioned hat?

Comment: Suggestions for this year WB al already closed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356787/158100

Comment: I don't want to be "very 2020" :)

Comment: But if I finish all of my chores and you finish thine
Then tonight we're gonna party like it's 1699

Comment: simply use the hats as masks. We always see funny idea of wearing hats

Comment: What's next? Questions don't get closed,  they *"get sent to the morgue"*?

Answer (score 7):

This will be my first Winter Bash, so I don't feel I have a whole lot of weight leaning in on this, since I've never experienced it before.

But...

With just how long the so-called "2020-ness" of this year has drone on, I'm personally just kind of tired of the masks at this point. I have nothing legitimate against them, and I most definitely recognize their importance. It's just that they're everywhere we look right now, and I personally find it getting a little... tiresome. It's like a constant reminder of just how crazy, ridiculous, and broken this year has been, on just about every level.

That said, I really, really like [the sentiment in @CodyGray's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403592), I think it's an excellent one. Making a mockery of the upside-down nature of 2020 to have a little fun may be *exactly* what we all need right now, and it will no doubt come in little ways regardless.

I just also think that silly hats seems expressive and fun and goofy as-is, and it just sounds more fun to me personally than masks do.

Answer (score 3):

Although apparently quite unpopular each time it is proposed, I actually think this is a good idea. I was one of the few upvoters [the first time it was proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356787). It is a very appropriate variation on the established theme that would require minimal changes to the back-end tooling, relieving an already-overloaded development team who presumably has limited time for "fun".

From the upvoted objections that I see, most people are saying that 2020 hasn't been much fun, so why celebrate it? I think of it not so much as a celebration but a mockery—having fun at the *expense* of 2020 as the year comes to an end. Come to think of it, that's how I see a lot of things.

Anyway…the way that Stack Exchange implements "hats" actually makes it fairly easy for you to think of them and use them as "masks". The "hat" glyphs just get overlaid dynamically on top of your avatar. You are presented with a tool on your profile page that allows you to select one of your earned hats from a cache, reposition it on top of your avatar, and resize it. There was never any requirement to literally wear it like a hat. In past years, plenty of people have chosen to wear certain hats like they were masks, essentially covering the "face" of their avatar. Part of the fun of Winter Bash is making an earned hat harmonize well with your gravatar, and users share their inspired creations on the Meta Stack Exchange site in a Q&A created expressly for that purpose.

Besides, I'm almost *certain* that one of the "hats" you will be able to earn during Winter Bash 2020 will be a mask. Maybe for contributing to the successful closure of an off-topic question? :-)

Comment: I understand your thinking, but.... what if someone has relatives dead from COVID-19? It won't be fun for them, right?

Comment: I think folks with relatives dead from Covid-19 would be more likely to want to make *sure* folks are wearing masks to stop the spread and hate seeing those without, perceived as spreading a disease which killed a loved one. Kind of like how one can appreciate (rather than be traumatized by) seeing bikers with helmets after losing someone to a crash that wouldn't have taken them if they'd had a helmet on.

Comment: There may even be [some people](https://www.nydailynews.com/new-york/ny-vendor-harlem-pushed-killed-20201008-dm7m77te6vg3fnsyykbnputs6m-story.html) who find hats to be insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's (also) masks now...

[image]

Comment: Happy now? ....

Comment: Nah, I prefer my sunglasses :D

Answer (score 1):

No, I wouldn't like this.

There has already been a proposal for a mask hat, which is fine, considering the pandemic. But to change up something that happens every year...***no***.

I don't want to be very 2020.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Only last years "This Is Fine" and "Bûche de Noël" shows flames. How do we know no one knows anyone who died in a fire? One was called "Blue in the Face". How do we know no one died by drowning? (Sadness could also be triggered by the "Rubber Ducky"). Then there's "180°" which is a u-turn. How do we know that no-one died in traffic in an intersection? ... Also, everywhere I go people are wearing masks. Everywhere! I can't go into a shop without wearing one..

Comment: @Scratte Fair point.